# SDL2 pixel manipulation

Tags: c, sdl-2

I need to create a window, and fill all of its pixels with a color. This shouldn't be too hard, but after a hour or so I still can't get it working. Here is my code as it looks right now:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    enum {
        WIDTH = 640,
        HEIGHT = 480
    };
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow(
        "SDL test",
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
        WIDTH,
        HEIGHT,
        SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN
    );
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    SDL_Texture* texture = SDL_CreateTexture(renderer,
        SDL_PIXELFORMAT_RGBA8888,
        SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_STREAMING,
        WIDTH,
        HEIGHT
    );
    SDL_Surface* surface = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(
        0,
        WIDTH,
        HEIGHT,
        32,
        0x00000000,
        0x00000000,
        0x00000000,
        0xff000000
    );
    Uint32 gray = SDL_MapRGBA(surface->format, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0x1E, 0xFF);
    Uint32 red = SDL_MapRGBA(surface->format, 0xFA, 0x32, 0x32, 0xFF);

    int i, j;
    Uint32* pixels32 = (Uint32*) surface->pixels;
    for (i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j)
        {
            pixels32[i * WIDTH + j] = j%10 ? gray : red;
        }
    }
    SDL_UpdateTexture(texture, NULL, surface->pixels, surface->pitch);

    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

    int quit = 0;
    SDL_Event event;
    while (!quit)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) != 0)
        {
            if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                quit = 1;
        }
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface(surface);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

But it shows a white window. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you `SDL_RenderPresent` when you're in the shutdown phase of your program?

Comment: @Rhymoid Oh that's a mistake, when I wanted to move the `SDL_FreeSurface` function I moved it too. Now I see a black window, great.

Comment: At least it's a different colour. Now, have you tried actually blitting the texture to the surface, using [`SDL_RenderCopy`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy) (or its -Ex variant)?

Comment: @Rhymoid It worked when I put it bettween the `SDL_UpdateTexture` and `SDL_RenderPresent` functions. Thanks! If you post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created a texture, but you haven't drawn it yet. In order to draw it on a surface, you still need to call [`SDL_RenderCopy`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderCopy).